# Azure Databricks Integration with Azure Git Repos

Tags: azure, github, databricks, azure-databricks, git-repo

1. We have tried to integrate the databricks notebook with a repository in Azure Repo. But, we are getting this below error

Error while syncing Git history: Response from Azure DevOps Services: status code: 500, reason phrase: ?{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"Unable to complete authentication for user due to looping logins","typeName":"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Identity.IdentityLoopingLoginException, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi","typeKey":"IdentityLoopingLoginException","errorCode":0,"eventId":4207}

Both Azure DevOps Services organization and Databricks located in the same tenant.

Repos Link format: https://dev.azure.com/myorg/project/_git/repo

2. When we tried valid token with GitHub getting an this below error.
   [image]

Comment: Have you tried opening your databricks workspace in incognito mode? Just to be sure it's not a caching problem.

Comment: also, have you checked the Git settings in the your User settings (click on User icon top right)

Comment: @Simon Nobel- Yes, I have cleared browser's cache and tried with incognito but it does not help. The integration with GitHub's public repo working now, but not private repos. Still facing integration issues with Azure DevOps repos.

Comment: @Alex Ott-I have double checked databricks git integration settings, everything is fine.

Comment: Consider reporting this at https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=problem as the Microsoft engineering teams can take the reference codes to check how the problem looks on their end.

Comment: @Simon, Thanks very much. I will do it.